# How to use mysql event scheduler in codeigniter model

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, model

**SOLVED**

I have this block of codes which will insert data to all unique email_address available on emp_leave_balance table. The problem is it doesn't work even though it didnt catch error. I tried this code in cmd and it works perfectly. I'm not sure if codeigniter accept this kind of query or not.

**MODEL**

```
public function insert_credit_points_data($email){
    try{

        $sql = "DELIMITER $$ 
        CREATE EVENT ecp 
        ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS NOW() DO 
        BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO emp_leave_balance (balance, date_from, date_to, leave_type, earned, date_filed, action_taken,email_address) 
        SELECT (1.25+balance), NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE), 'Vacation', 1.25, NOW(), 'CREDITED',".$email." FROM emp_leave_balance where email_address = ".$email." ORDER BY balance DESC LIMIT 1; 
        END$$ 
        DELIMITER ;";

        $this->db->query($sql); 

    }catch(Exception $e){
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

[SQL ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPFdT.png)

**NEW PROBLEM**

I'm trying to loop the insert query based on the number of distinct email address available in my table. The problem is my loop doesn't work.

```
$sql = "CREATE EVENT ecp ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS NOW() DO 
        BEGIN
        DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email_address)) FROM emp_leave_balance);
            simple_loop: LOOP
                INSERT INTO emp_leave_balance (balance, date_from, date_to, leave_type, earned, date_filed, action_taken,email_address) 
                SELECT (1.25+balance), NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE), 'Vacation', 1.25, NOW(), 'CREDITED','".$email."' FROM emp_leave_balance where email_address = '".$email."' ORDER BY balance DESC LIMIT 1;
            SET x = x + 1;
            IF x<counter THEN
                LEAVE simple_loop;
            END IF;
            END LOOP simple_loop;
        END";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very few (if any) functions in CI throw exceptions, if they do it is usually due to a native php function. In your case `query()` will return boolean depending on whether or not it succeeded so the try catch block is superfluous.

With that being said, all the `query()` function does is execute a query so I don't see if having a problem handling anything phpmyadmin can't. I would suggest going into the `database.php` file and changing `db_debug` to true. This should help you find the exact cause of the error.

Comment: thank you for this. I got the error but I still don't know how to fix it. Can you help me about it. I'll add the error at my post

Comment: I've met a new problem. I'm trying to make a loop inside my query but my loop doesnt work? Any idea how can I implement loop base on the number of distinct email address avaible in my table?

Comment: I'm really not all that good with advanced sql stuff... Sorry.

Comment: But you shouldn't edit your question - instead start a new one with the proper tags